# How to use Codeigniter Select with sum if?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What I want to do is use sum if in codeigniter, it's got error when I run in browser, but I query in MYSQL, there are not error and working nicely.

**Here is my code**

```
$this->db->select('sum(if(`monitoring_type` = 1,1,0)) AS independent,sum(if(`monitoring_type` = 2,1,0)) AS buddy,count(*) AS TM, rate_info.qm_title');
$this->db->from('qm.recordings');
$this->db->join('qm.rate_info', 'recordings.record_id = rate_info.record_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

**my Error**
[image]

**MYSQL**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `FALSE` as the second parameter to

`$this->db->select('your Query', FALSE);`

**Update:**

It removes the escape identifiers (the backticks) from the select statement which codeigniter does by default for each query.  So

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2` FROM table
```

will become

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table
```

Comment: @Prabhukiran can you explain me why FALSE is required?